# How do I swap columns with a specific indexes in java 2d arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

So I've been trying to solve following problem:

Given a two-dimensional array (matrix) and the two numbers: i and j. Swap the columns with indexes i and j within the matrix.

Input contains matrix dimensions n and m, not exceeding 100, then the elements of the matrix, then the indexes i and j.

Sample Input 1:

- 3 4
- 11 12 13 14
- 21 22 23 24
- 31 32 33 34
- 0 1

Sample Output 1:

- 12 11 13 14
- 22 21 23 24
- 32 31 33 34

In order to solve it, I wrote following code:

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int rows = scanner.nextInt();
        int tables = scanner.nextInt();
        int[][] matrix = new int[rows][tables];

        int i = scanner.nextInt();
        int j = scanner.nextInt();

        for (int w = 0; w < rows; w++){
            int temp = matrix[w][i];
            matrix[w][i] = matrix[w][j];
            matrix[w][j] = temp;
        }

        System.out.print(matrix);
    }
}
```

And the error is Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 11 out of bounds for length 4 at Main.main(Main.java:15).

What might be the problem and solution to it?

Comment: What values did you input for ```rows```, ```tables```, ```i``` and ```j```?

Comment: You are reading the first two columns of the first row into `i` and `j`. You are missing a loop to populate the matrix.

Comment: `11` would only occur if you typed in `11` (or higher) as one of the inputs. Your examples do not show that. The code works with an empty array, while your examples show numbers that weren't specified in the code. Your code does not match your example, so the error is probably occuring due to something you are not showing us. I just ran the code with the same inputs (3 and 4, 0 and 1) and I did not get the same exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 11 out of bounds for length 4 at Main.main(Main.java:15).**

Above error is because you are directly reading values into i and j but you forgot setting the values inside the matrix[][] as said by vince and jim in the comments.

Use loop to set the values

```
  for(int k=0;k<rows;k++){
      for(int l=0;l<cols;l++){
             matrix[k][l]=scanner.nextInt();
      }   
   }
```

and then loop through rows to swap values

Here goes the code

Live: https://onlinegdb.com/rJJ-kMTUL

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int rows = scanner.nextInt();
        int cols = scanner.nextInt();
        int[][] matrix = new int[rows][cols];
        for(int k=0;k<rows;k++){
         for(int l=0;l<cols;l++){
             matrix[k][l]=scanner.nextInt();
         }   
        }
        int i = scanner.nextInt();
        int j = scanner.nextInt();
        for(int k=0;k<rows;k++){
        int temp =  matrix[k][i];
        matrix[k][i] = matrix[k][j];
        matrix[k][j]=temp;      
        }
         for(int k=0;k<rows;k++){
         for(int l=0;l<cols;l++){
             System.out.print( matrix[k][l]+" ");
         }
         System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The size of the array is still set, so accessing this empty array within the bounds won't throw the exception; the array is filled with `0`, but elements do exist in the array, even if he didn't populate it yet. After running his code, I did not get an exception. It's most likely the numbers he's entering into the console for `i` and `j`.

Comment: i ran his code and was giving input after giving first row this error was thrown

Comment: Well you should know that array elements are defaulted, so as long as he sets the size of the array, an error will not be thrown due to an index access. His error shows an attempt of accessing index 11 when only 4 indices existed. What did your error show?